# check if a value exists in dynamodb table using python and fetch that record

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-dynamodb, boto3, dynamodb-queries

I am new to Dynamodb and learning currently. I am using python to query dynamodb to get some records based on a IF condition.

I have a dynamodb table `cus_token`, has only two attributes a) customerId and b) token

[image: Token Table]

When a user provides token, check if that token exists in the cus_token table, and if it exists I want to query out and fetch the customerID for that token. I tried to to do it this way

Suppose
`user_input = "Rooxp9"` (this is a token in the cus_token table)

first get all the values with token attribute

```
import boto3
import json

def gettokens(y):
    dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
    table = dynamodb.Table('cus_token')
    response = table.scan()

    tokens = []
    for i in response['Items']:
        nameList.append(i['token'])

    return tokens

temp = gettokens(cus_token)
```

Check using IF condition

```
for item in temp:
    if item == user_input:
        "Here I want to write the code to fetch the customerID"
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you'd like to fetch a `customerID` given a `token`.

To do this with your current table design, you'd want to use a [Filter Expression](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Scan.html#Scan.FilterExpression) to ask DynamoDB to return all attributes where the `token` is equal to the user input.  For example, here's a snippet in pseudocode:

```
response = table.scan({"FilterExpression": "#token = :token",
                       "ExpressionAttributeNames": {"#token":"token"},
                       "ExpressionAttributeValues": {":token": {"S": <user_input>}})
```

There's no need to scan the entire database, return it to your application, then filter the results in your application.

If you are just getting started with DynamoDB, I'd highly recommend [The DynamoDB Guide website](https://www.dynamodbguide.com/).  It does a great job explaining DynamoDB to beginners.

Comment: I also want to validate whether user given token matches with the token existing the in table.
Only If the token matches, I need to fetch the corresponding customerID

Comment: This scan operation will only return items where the token matches what you ask for (the user input).  If there is no match, you will get no results.  There is no need for additional validation.  By default, the scan operation will return all attributes in the matching items, meaning you will have the CustomerID in your results.